# Can I delete folders in /lib/modules/ after calling "apt-get purge"

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I've already call `apt-get purge` to uninstall the old kernels. But some error occured during the purge that caused the folders to be left behind. It said the folder was not empty so it couldn't delete. To free up disk space can I manually delete those folders that I've purged?

```
1.1M    ./4.15.0-20-generic
60M     ./4.15.0-32-generic <-- I've purged this
60M     ./4.15.0-30-generic <-- and this
236M    ./4.15.0-33-generic <-- this is my current one
```

Can I also remove some of these packages?

```
un  linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic                       <none>                          <none>                          (no description available)
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-30                               4.15.0-30.32                    all                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic                       4.15.0-30.32                    amd64                           Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-32                               4.15.0-32.35                    all                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic                       4.15.0-32.35                    amd64                           Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-33                               4.15.0-33.36                    all                             Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic                       4.15.0-33.36                    amd64                           Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic                         4.15.0-20.21                    amd64                           Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic                         4.15.0-33.36                    amd64                           Signed kernel image generic
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-20-generic                <none>                          <none>                          (no description available)
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-33-generic                <none>                          <none>                          (no description available)
rc  linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic                       4.15.0-20.21                    amd64                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-4.15.0-30-generic                       4.15.0-30.32                    amd64                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-4.15.0-32-generic                       4.15.0-32.35                    amd64                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic                       4.15.0-33.36                    amd64                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic                 4.15.0-20.21                    amd64                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok so I decided to just take the risk and manually delete the folder under `/lib/modules` and had no problem rebooting my server.

Comment: I did the same and also experienced no problem

Comment: See NotoriousPyro's response. Find the installed packages with dpgk -l | grep -E 'linux-.+-[0-9]+' , and delete the older packages. Just make sure you don't delete the current version packages ( check with uname -r ) If you removed the folders manually, APT's information is somehow broken.

Comment: Look for linux-image- , linux-headers- , linux-modules- , linux-modules-extra-   with old version numbers

Answer (score 4):

You can safely remove the corresponding version of packages to the version of the kernel that you removed. In your example because you are missing the corresponding kernel versions for the following, so you can ask your package manager to also remove:

```
linux-headers-4.15.0-30
linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic
linux-modules-4.15.0-30-generic
linux-headers-4.15.0-32
linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic
linux-modules-4.15.0-32-generic
```

Comment: +1 because this is the right way to delete the files, through apt

Answer (score 2):

I had about 30 /lib/modules directories and modules from kernels no longer in use and I deleted them all freeing up over 5GB of space. I don't know why they don't get deleted when I delete the kernels with ukuu. It seems this  hasn't caused a problem yet.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into the same predicament. As some of the others mentioned, I was also able to safely delete folders in /lib/modules. I believe the error you ran into was due to a package that couldn't install due to not enough disk space. In my case, I tried fixing the packages with `apt-get -f install` but ran into a `No space left on device` error. I was able to successfully remove the old kernels using `apt-get autoremove -f`. That freed up quite a bit of space. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

this is the method I used

after `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`

which returned...

rc  linux-image-4.19.0-14-amd64

and

`ls -l /lib/modules/`

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 16 22:57 **4.19.0-14-amd64**

using the following command

`sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.19.0-14-amd64`

removed the folder under `/lib/modules` as well as package and install files located under
`/var/lib/dpkg/info/`

Comment: if yoou do so, and its your current kernel you will kill your system, thats a dangerouse action

Comment: of course it's not my current kernel... I am using 5.10.46-4-amd64 on Bullseye

there were a few more entries from way back that I removed this way too... there from when I was on Buster...I was only using 4.19.0-14-amd64 as an example

this method, using dpkg --purge is a more advisable and efficient solution than manually deleting folders

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not Ubuntu, but in CentOS the "current version" of the kernel I guess resides there so you can't delete all of them.

Nor is it safe to manually delete "old ones" in case you were in the middle of installing a new one but the transaction hadn't succeeded.  You won't know exactly which one to delete.

`yum autoremove` doesn't seem to remove old ones for whatever reason.  It's even recommended to keep two versions around in case you need an old one: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/remove-old-kernels-rhel-centos-8/#Best_practices_to_remove_old_kernels

You can manually remove packages for the older ones:

https://www.nixcraft.com/t/can-i-delete-lib-modules-directory-in-linux-safely/1934/2

So the take home lesson is "only delete kernels that are older" (see above link describing how to check) and "prefer deleting them via removing their package" to manually nuking their directories.

Also note that if you do accidentally remove the "current kernel" you may be able to recover if you happen to have a few older kernels still kicking around.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to remove those is to uninstall unused `linux-image-` and `linux-headers-` packages.

```
# apt list --installed | grep -P "linux-(image|headers)-"
# apt remove linux-image-5.10.0-10-amd64
# apt remove linux-headers-5.10.0-10-amd64
```

But if you have manually-installed DKMS modules, uninstalling `linux-image-` and `linux-headers-` packages doesn't clean those up, which leads to subfolders in `/lib/modules/` remaining.

Run `dkms status` to list installed DKMS modules (or run `ls -l /var/lib/dkms/*/`)

Remove modules pointing to uninstalled kernels using `dkms remove`:

```
# dkms status
acpi-call, 1.1.0, 5.10.0-10-amd64, x86_64: installed
acpi-call, 1.1.0, 5.10.0-13-amd64, x86_64: installed
acpi-call, 1.1.0, 5.10.0-14-amd64, x86_64: installed

# dkms remove acpi-call/1.1.0 -k 5.10.0-10-amd64

acpi_call.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.10.0-10-amd64/

# dkms remove acpi-call/1.1.0 -k 5.10.0-13-amd64

acpi_call.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.10.0-13-amd64/

#
```